# Tikzpicture-figure: Order plot data (asc/desc)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using a tikzpicture for plotting. the values I want to plot are typical (X,Y) pairs. The x-value is an uninteresting id-value. I want to order the bins ascending/descending according to the y-value, but how do I do that?
The figure seems to automatically take the x-values for ordering, how can I override that? (I am not particularly fixed to tikzpicture - its just the first thing that actually worked and displayed the plot....)
Following minimal-working example, how could I achieve a reordering according to the y-value?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{OgAns}{rgb}{0, 0.8, 0.4} 
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
1   30
2   44
4   26
3   39
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[   
            ybar stacked,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=100,
            bar width=5pt,
            legend style={at={(0.35, -0.4)},anchor=south west},
            legend columns=-1            
          ]
          \addplot[ybar,fill=OgAns]  file {testdata.dat}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can sort the table using the `pgfplotstable` package. It provides a command `\pgfplotstablesort[<options>]{<output table name>}{<input table>}`. To read the `testdata.dat` file and sort it in descending order according to the second column, storing the sorted table in a macro called `\datatablesorted`, you'd use the following command:

```
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key=1, sort cmp=int >]{\datatablesorted}{testdata.dat}
```

To plot the sorted table, you would then use the following command:

```
\addplot [fill=green]  table [x expr=\coordindex] {\datatablesorted};
```

The `x expr=\coordindex` is necessary to make sure that the bars are plotted in the order  they appear in the sorted table, otherwise they'd be plotted according to the value in the first column.

To get the right labels for the bars, include `xticklabels from table={\datatablesorted}{0}` in the `axis` options, which instructs PGFPlots to take the labels from the first column of the `\datatablesorted` table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
1   30
2   44
4   26
3   39
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstablesort[sort key=1, sort cmp=int >]{\datatablesorted}{testdata.dat}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[   
            ybar,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=100,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabels from table={\datatablesorted}{0}
          ]
          \addplot [fill=green]  table [x expr=\coordindex] {\datatablesorted}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]