# PGFPlots: How to sort the bars based on y values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a bar chart that looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code that I used to generate the plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits=0.03,
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar=1pt,
    ylabel=F1 Score, 
    xlabel=objects,
    bar width=10pt,
    x=0.45cm,
    ymin=0,
    axis on top,
    ymax=1,
    xtick= \empty,
    xticklabel style={rotate=-90,  xshift=0.2cm},
   symbolic x coords={barkely hide bones,
cherokee easy tee-shirt,
clorox utility brush, 
cloud b plush bear,
command hooks,
cool shot glue sticks,                
crayola 24 ct,                        
creativity chenille stems ,            
dasani water bottle,                 
dove beauty bar,                      
dr browns bottle brush,              
easter turtle sippy cup ,            
elmers washable no run school glue ,   
expo dry erase board eraser ,         
fiskars scissors red,               
fitness gear 3lb dumbbell,        
folgers classic roast coffee,
hanes tube socks,                      
i am a bunny book,      
jane eyre dvd,                   
kleenex paper towels, 
kleenex tissue box,
kyjen squeakin eggs plush puppies,
laugh out loud joke book,
oral b toothbrush green,
oral b toothbrush red,
peva shower curtain liner,
platinum pets dog bowl,
rawlings baseball,
rolodex jumbo pencil cup,
safety first outlet plugs,
scotch bubble mailer,
scotch duct tape,
soft white lightbulb,
staples index cards,
ticonderoga 12 pencils,
up glucose bottle,
womens knit gloves,
woods extension cord 
},
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
            \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
        },
    nodes near coords={%
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
        },
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt,rotate=90,xshift=0.3cm},
    axis lines*=left,
    clip=false
    ]
\addplot coordinates {
(barkely hide bones,0.8780)
(cherokee easy tee-shirt,0.8210)
(clorox utility brush,0.8210)
(cloud b plush bear,0.8360)
(command hooks,0.8770) 
(cool shot glue sticks,0.7930)                 
(crayola 24 ct,0.8110)                         
(creativity chenille stems ,0.7610)             
(dasani water bottle,0.7960)                  
(dove beauty bar,0.7400)                       
(dr browns bottle brush,0.9400)               
(easter turtle sippy cup ,0.8790)             
(elmers washable no run school glue ,0.8380)    
(expo dry erase board eraser ,0.8240)          
(fiskars scissors red,0.4780)                
(fitness gear 3lb dumbbell,0.7630)         
(folgers classic roast coffee,0.8980) 
(hanes tube socks,0.8890)                       
(i am a bunny book,0.9060)       
(jane eyre dvd,0.8930)                    
(kleenex paper towels,0.8880)
(kleenex tissue box,0.9420) 
(kyjen squeakin eggs plush puppies,0.8600) 
(laugh out loud joke book,0.8940) 
(oral b toothbrush green,0.7460) 
(oral b toothbrush red,0.6790) 
(peva shower curtain liner,0.9160) 
(platinum pets dog bowl,0.9170) 
(rawlings baseball,0.8580) 
(rolodex jumbo pencil cup,0.9260) 
(safety first outlet plugs,0.8340) 
(scotch bubble mailer,0.8940) 
(scotch duct tape,0.8100) 
(soft white lightbulb,0.8410) 
(staples index cards,0.8470) 
(ticonderoga 12 pencils,0.9500) 
(up glucose bottle,0.7860) 
(womens knit gloves,0.8870) 
(woods extension cord,0.8880)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want the bars to be sorted automatically based on the y value. Could someone please help in figuring this out?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198461/tikzpicture-figure-order-plot-data-asc-desc

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah: Thanks a lot for the link. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: If I was a bit too quick with closing, let me know, and we'll reopen.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Np. I got the answer I needed.